# WCF SSL Endpoints reporting 404, no endpoints listening

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, ssl

We have a WCF web service that, unfortunately, has to use SOAP 1.1 + SSL, thus why I'm using basicHttpBinding and not wsHttpBinding. I believe that my web.config is in order, as I have compared it to countless others on stackoverflow and MSDN articles. I haven't had any luck with the other issue solutions because everybody seems to be using wsHttpBinding for all of the SSL binding examples.

Many of the suggestions on StackOverflow lead to server configuration errors such as [SSL Headers](http://geekswithblogs.net/rakker/archive/2008/07/03/123562.aspx), but I have confirmed with the people that manage our IIS that the SSL port bindings and SSL Host Headers are configured correctly (as far as we can tell). We do however use a **wildcard certificate,** which I've read can complicate this process like in this (removed due to new user limit on links), though my SSL is working and the session is encrypted.

I'm hoping its something simple in the config that I'm missing because I've been staring at it for too many hours/days on end.

When I try to call the service from  WcfTestService.exe or a basic .net application, I get the following error.

> **There was no endpoint listening at
>   https:// subdomain.domain.us:8091/SalesService/SalesService.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.**
>
> Server stack trace:
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException (WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request,
>   HttpAbortReason abortReason)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway,
>   ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
>   Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan
>   timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   IServiceRC.RestrictedProduct(String
>   line1)    at
>   ServiceRCClient.RestrictedProduct(String
>   line1)
>
> Inner Exception: The remote
>   server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)

And here is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SalesService.ServiceRCbehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceRCbind" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
        receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
        bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
        messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
        useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
          maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address=""
    binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceRCbind"
    contract="SalesService.IServiceRC"/>
    </client>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SalesService.ServiceRCbehavior" name="SalesService.ServiceRC">
        <endpoint address="" listenUri="SalesService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SalesService.IServiceRC" bindingConfiguration="ServiceRCbind"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="https://subdomain.domain.us:8091/SalesService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
        <!--<add prefix="https://subdomain.domain.us:8091/SalesService/"/>-->
      </baseAddressPrefixFilters>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Another thing I've considered is doing custom endpoints like in the previously linked solution, but I don't think my situation specifically requires it and would only complicate things.

Any input/references would be extremely appreciated.

Edit: [Here](http://barleyalive.com/RC.wsdl) is a link to the text of the wsdl generated by IIS (only edited the domain name for anonymity)

Comment: When you view the .svc file in a browser, it shows the correct url when it says to use SvcUtil.exe to generate a proxy?

Comment: Have you or someone checked to see if the service site/application has HTTPS configured to use port 8091 in IIS? The default HTTPS port is 443. When IIS says 404 it usually means the URL path is invalid somehow. Also, has any client been able to call the service or get the WSDL from it successfully?

Comment: Yes Nate It shows the correct url and when I use SvcUtil.exe it pulls down all of the information correctly and generates the Service and output files.

Sixto, the HTTPS is bound to 8091 and when viewing the svc file, the browser reports that the SSL is active and the connection is encrypted, so I'm assuming all of that is correct. I was able to call the WSDL using WCFTestClient.exe and it pulled down all of the methods and their appropriate input parameters.

Comment: Would posting the WSDL file be beneficial to anyone? Everything there seems to look pretty standard though.

Comment: it'd be great if you can post the WSDL file. Please post WSDL browsed from IIS not for Service hosted in VS Web Development Server.

Comment: Here is a link to the [wsdl file](http://barleyalive.com/RC.wsdl) changed only for anonymity. This was the one browsed as it is hosted in IIS, as requested. Thanks again.